# Get the id of a table and insert in other column as foreign key

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi m trying to Get the id of a table and insert in other column as foreign key but it is not saving into db and not showing any error

blade file:

```
  <form method="post" action="{{ route('day.store' , $form->id) }}">
              @csrf
            <button type="submit" id="save" class="btn btn-primary">Add this DataTime</button>
            <b><span id="showdatetime"></span></b>
            </form>
```

route:

```
   Route::post('/form/day', 'DayController@store')->name('day.store');
```

controller:

```
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
    Day::Create([
        'form_id' => $form_id,
        'selecteddatetime' => $date,

    ]);

    return back();

  }
```

model:

```
  protected $guarded = [];

  public function form()
  {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Form');
  }
```

Comment: What's the error exactly

Comment: nthing no error or data isn't saving into db

Comment: Assign your newly created instance to a variable and dump it, For ex. `$day=Day::create....` then `dd($day)`. Show us what you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing parameter in route but you are not accepting this in your store method so Change this

```
public function store(Request $request)
  {
    Day::Create([
        'form_id' => $form_id,
        'selecteddatetime' => $date,

    ]);

    return back();

  }
```

to

```
 public function store(Request $request, $form)
  {
    Day::Create([
        'form_id' => $form_id,
        'selecteddatetime' => $date,

    ]);

    return back();

  }
```

in your model add below code

```
 protected $fillable = ['form_id', 'selecteddatetime'];

 protected $guarded = ['id','form_id'];

  public function form()
  {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Form');
  }
```

Hope it helps.

Thanks

Comment: data isn't saving and not showing any error check the updated question